# Android Convert DateTime to EEE, d MMM yyyy

Tags: android, datetime

I am trying to convert the following data time to EEE, d MMM yyyy format but kept getting Unparsable date format. Can some one please help. I couldn't find anything on the web that helped.

Here is the code

```
String datestr = "2017-01-12T00:00:00Z";
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z", Locale.US);
Date convertedDateStart = new Date();
try {
      convertedDateStart = dateFormat.parse(datestr);
      camp_new.startdate = convertedDateStart;
} catch (ParseException e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Any help wound be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The date string `"2017-01-12T00:00:00Z"` cannot be parsed with your format `"EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z"`; the fields are the wrong type or in the wrong place.

The format for your `datestr` `"2017-01-12T00:00:00Z"` should be:

```
       yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ
```

You need to initialize the `SimpleDateFormat` with this format to parse `datestr`.

The format `"EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z"` would parse a date that looks like

```
       Thu, 1 Jan 2017 00:00:00 Z
```

Read the docs to understand the difference between `parse()` and `format()`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to parse it first, store it as a `Date` object and then use another SimpleDateFormat to format in the desired way.

```
String datestr = "2017-01-12T00:00:00Z";

SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ", Locale.US);
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat2 = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z", Locale.US);

Date date = dateFormat.parse(datestr);
String convertedDateStart = dateFormat2.format(date);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well This will Work For you if you want to **FORMAT** and get a Date String with that format..

```
        String datestr = "2017-01-12T00:00:00Z";
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'", Locale.US);

        try {
            date = dateFormat.parse(datestr);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z", Locale.US);

        datestr = dateFormat.format(date);

        System.out.println(datestr);
```

This will give you Thu, 12 Jan 2017 00:00:00 +0430 Date String.